# MySQL Insert into table, where name = id, if not exist, then insert name and use that ID

Tags: mysql, insert

I am producing a MySQL database that will store results for a particular sport. I have a table containing people, (PERSONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME), another table containing animals names (ANIMALID, ANIMALNAME).

Within the results table, I have the position, personid, animalid, and time. I want to create a query that will insert into the results table a large number of 'results'.
I have managed to create a simple query to look up a persons ID based on their firstname and last name, however I want to take this further and say 'If this person doesn't exist based on their firstname and lastname, insert this into the persons table, and then use their ID for the results'. The same will be the case for the animals.

Also, as a side note, would it be possible to create a sort of procedure that will run through a list of peoples names and animal, and insert it into the results table? (preferable with the above 'if not exist, then insert and use id' scheme)

Thanks,

Graham

Comment: Where is this *"list of peoples names and animals"*? In other tables? In an application?

Comment: It is extracted from PDF and Excel documents, so it is in plain text really, ie 1st "Joe Blogs" "Animal One", 2nd "Joey Bloogs" "Animal Two" etc.

Comment: I'd highly suggest against creating an index logic for yourself, as it is error prone, and the database can do that much better than you. Just create a unique composite index on the 2 name fields.

Comment: I do have a unique index on the two name fields, but I'm failing to see how that will help me? Sorry, very new to MySQL

Comment: If you already have a unique composite (!) index over these 2 name fields, you can not insert a second record with the same first and last name, as the index will prevent that. You could then just insert a record, then listen to the error message from the database.

Comment: In the question you also mention `position` in the results. Is that in the Excel data, too?

Comment: Thats what I have been doing, using INSERT IGNORE to mass add people and animals.

Comment: It is @ypercube, everything for the results table is outside of the database, in an excel sheet. Or txt document if thats easier to work with etc.

Comment: So, what are the columns in this sheet? PersonName, AnimalName, Position, (... what else)?

Comment: Position, PersonName (First and Last, not split), AnimalName, Errors (Numerical), Time

Comment: And I suppose these are for a specific race? And every race is in a different sheet/file?

Comment: Thats the one @ypercube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have some tables for Persons, Animals:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
  ( PersonID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , PersonName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT Person_PK
      PRIMARY KEY (PersonID)
  , CONSTRAINT PersonName_UQ 
      UNIQUE (PersonName)
  ) ;

CREATE TABLE Animal
  ( AnimalID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , AnimalName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT Animal_PK
      PRIMARY KEY (AnimalID)
  , CONSTRAINT AnimalName_UQ 
      UNIQUE (AnimalName)
  ) ;
```

and results:

```
CREATE TABLE Result
  ( RaceID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  , Position INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  , PersonID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
  , AnimalID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  , Errors INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , CompletionTime Time NULL DEFAULT NULL

  , CONSTRAINT Result_PK
      PRIMARY KEY (RaceID, Position)

  , CONSTRAINT Race_Person_UQ           -- assuming a Person cannot enter
      UNIQUE (RaceID, PersonID)                 -- a race twice

  , CONSTRAINT Race_Animal_UQ           -- assuming an Animal cannot enter
      UNIQUE (RaceID, AnimalID)                 -- a race twice

  , INDEX PersonID_IX (PersonID)                -- indexes for the Foreign Key
  , INDEX AnimalID_IX (AnimalID)                -- constraints:

  , CONSTRAINT Person_Result_FK     
      FOREIGN KEY (PersonID)
      REFERENCES Person (PersonID)
  , CONSTRAINT Animal_Result_FK     
      FOREIGN KEY (AnimalID)
      REFERENCES Animal (AnimalID)
  ) ;
```

I suggest you first bulk load the data (possibly with **[`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)** from `.txt` or `.csv` files) in a table in MySQL (supplying race IDS. If you can't supply raceIDs but you have race names, the tables should be adjusted accordingly). You should have a `Race` table as well, this is just a sample procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE BulkData
  ( RaceID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  , Position INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  , PersonName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  , AnimalName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  , Errors INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0          -- adjust datatypes according
  , CompletionTime Time NULL DEFAULT NULL           -- to your data
  ) ;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/results.txt' 
    INTO TABLE BulkData
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
           ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ;
```

Then you can manipulate them and insert them into the 2-3 tables. For `Person`:

```
INSERT INTO Person
    (PersonName)
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.PersonName
FROM
    BulkData AS b
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT 1
      FROM Person AS p
      WHERE p.PersonName = b.PersonName
    ) ;
```

Similar for `Animal`:

```
INSERT INTO Animal
    (AnimalName)
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.AnimalName
FROM
    BulkData AS b
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT 1
      FROM Animal AS a
      WHERE a.AnimalName = b.AnimalName
    ) ;
```

And then in `Result`:

```
INSERT INTO Result
    (RaceID, Position, PersonID, AnimalID, Errors, CompletionTime)
SELECT 
    b.RaceID, b.Position, p.PersonID, a.AnimalID, b.Errors, b.CompletionTime
FROM
    BulkData AS b
  JOIN
    Person AS p  ON p.PersonName = b.PersonName
  JOIN 
    Animal AS a  ON a.AnimalName = b.AnimalName
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT 1
      FROM Result AS r
      WHERE r.RaceID = b.RaceID
        AND r.PositionID = b.PositionID
    ) ;
```

If the importing results are satisfying, then you can empty the `BulkData` table and repeat the procedure with more files. The `NOT EXISTS` conditions will take care and not allow duplicates even if you try to load same data twice.

Comment: Much appreciated @ypercube, guess I was going about it the wrong way with my idea, thank you

Comment: I don't think your idea was wrong. You could probbaly write insert procedures that did what you described (if I understood you correctly). But when you have lots of data to load, it's easier to load them all in one (or few) shots and then manipulate them than inserting them row by row.